# Need Help for VB6 Code to C# Conversion

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

```
Private Sub SetEvents()
  WR_mfSetEvent E_EVENT_CODELINE, AddressOf MFS100_OnCodeline
  WR_mfSetEvent E_EVENT_DOCUMENTDONE, AddressOf MFS100_OnDocumentDone
  WR_mfSetEvent E_EVENT_ERROR, AddressOf MFS100_OnError
  WR_mfSetEvent E_EVENT_ALLDONE, AddressOf MFS100_OnAllDone
End Sub

Enum EventEnum
E_EVENT_CODELINE = 0
E_EVENT_RAWIMAGEFRONT
E_EVENT_RAWIMAGEBACK
E_EVENT_RAWMICRBUFFER
E_EVENT_RAWOCRBUFFER
E_EVENT_DOCUMENTDONE
E_EVENT_WARNING
E_EVENT_ERROR
E_EVENT_ALLDONE
End Enum
```

How can i convert this code to C# ?

Update 1: I have problem with Scan and ScanFeeder. ScanFeeder returns an MICR code but i cant handle it. The Scan function gets an read write memory error.

```
    ' mflib routines
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare Function mfInit Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal fileIni As String) As Long
Declare Function mfClose Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfTrace Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal level As Long, ByVal msg As String) As Long
Declare Function mfTraceSet Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal tracelevel As Long, ByVal maxlen As Long, ByVal fullpathname As String) As Long
Declare Function mfSetParam Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal paramCode As Long, ByVal paramValue As String) As Long
Declare Function mfReset Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfGetStatus Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal ret_statusbuffer As String) As Long
Declare Function mfScan Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal font As Long, ByVal timeout As Long, ByVal ret_codeline As String, ByRef ret_maxchars As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfEject Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal pocket As Long, ByVal timeout As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfCalib Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal calibID As Long, ByVal mode As Long, ByRef ret_value As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfScanFeeder Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mode As Long, ByVal font As Long, ByVal timeout As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfSetEvent Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal eventId As Long, ByVal callback As Long) As Long
Declare Function mfGetErrorDescription Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal errorCode As Long, ByVal ret_errorDescription As String) As Long
Declare Function mfIQALoadConfig Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal configfile As String) As Long
Declare Function mfIQASetParameter Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal paramid As Long, ByVal value As String) As Long
Declare Function mfIQATestFile Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal mask As Long, ByVal front As String, ByVal rear As String) As Long
Declare Function mfIQAGetErrorDescription Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal errorid As Long, ByVal desc As String, ByVal maxlen As Long) As Long
Declare Sub mfSort Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" (ByVal pocket As Long)
Declare Function mfStop Lib "mflib.dll.stdcall" () As Long
```

Update 2:

```
Public Function WR_mfSetEvent(eventId As Long, callback As Long) As Long
    WriteEvent "  event " & GetEventName(eventId)
    WR_mfSetEvent = mfSetEvent(eventId, callback)
    WriteEventMFSRes WR_mfSetEvent
    CScannerForm.lsTest.AddItem ("mfSetEvent : " & WR_mfSetEvent)
End Function

Public Sub WriteEventMFSRes(res As Long)
  If res >= 0 Then
    If res <> 1 Then WriteEventRes " (" & res & ")"
  Else
    WriteEventRes " (" & res & "='" & WR_mfGetErrorDescription(res) & "')"
  End If
End Sub
```

Update 2: is this the correct way. I get callback in this way

```
MFS100_CodeLineDelegate OnCodeline = new MFS100_CodeLineDelegate(MFS100_OnCodeLine);
                Adress = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnCodeline);
                mfSetEvent(0, Adress.ToInt32());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the enum is easy; C# uses a very similar syntax (with a few curly braces thrown in):

```
enum EventEnum
{
    E_EVENT_CODELINE = 0,
    E_EVENT_RAWIMAGEFRONT,
    E_EVENT_RAWIMAGEBACK,
    E_EVENT_RAWMICRBUFFER,
    E_EVENT_RAWOCRBUFFER,
    E_EVENT_DOCUMENTDONE,
    E_EVENT_WARNING,
    E_EVENT_ERROR,
    E_EVENT_ALLDONE
}
```

The `SetEvents` sub would become a function with a return type of `void`, all method calls must be wrapped in parentheses (also true in VB.NET), and you don't need the `AddressOf` operator:

```
private void SetEvents()
{
    WR_mfSetEvent(E_EVENT_CODELINE, MFS100_OnCodeline);
    WR_mfSetEvent(E_EVENT_DOCUMENTDONE, MFS100_OnDocumentDone);
    WR_mfSetEvent(E_EVENT_ERROR, MFS100_OnError);
    WR_mfSetEvent(E_EVENT_ALLDONE, MFS100_OnAllDone);
}
```

You might have to implement those functions (`MFS100_OnCodeline`, for example) as [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). C# has an entirely different syntax model for assigning functions to delegates/events, but you're not raising the typical events built into VB 6. This is some kind of custom library, so it's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly how they are defined and what they do.

Comment: +1 for answer, FYI: http://converter.telerik.com/ - but not for VB6 specific stuff.

Comment: @Code - Shoudn't the parameters that were AddressOf be a reference to the parameter?  It has been over 15 years since I even looked at a single line of VB6 code.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know what you mean by "reference to the parameter". `AddressOf` has *lots* of uses in VB 6, but the most common one that I'm familiar with is to get the address of a particular function. [This upgrade reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkasf56d.aspx) gives more information on migrating VB 6 code that uses `AddressOf` to VB.NET delegates. That's what I had in mind.

Comment: @Code - I simple mean make it a pointer for instance making it a( out, ref ) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [pInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/). This will give you an idea of how to access stuff defined in DLLs.

I did a search for `WR_mfSetEvent` but found nothing - is this a private library you're using? Without knowing *what* you're doing, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: What does P/Invoke have to do with converting VB 6 code to C#? Did you read the question? He wants to convert the code he's shown, not call it from a DLL.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to convert vb6 code that use c++ dll to c# but i have some problems with it.

Comment: Can you post the signature(s) for the C++ functions?

Comment: @Cody Gray, I was just guessing he was calling into a DLL from the way his code looked: The (undocumented) VB6 `AddressOf` operator returns a function pointer and is mostly used for calling into other DLLs (e.g. win32 api).

Comment: @Daren: Yeah, it looks like you turned out to be right. Most people are better at mind-reading than I am. I still don't think the suggestion to look at P/Invoke is a very complete one. pinvoke.net is decided to calling the Windows API, which is totally different from most C++ DLLs. And `AddressOf` is *definitely* documented. It was a big deal when VB 5 introduced it. Most of the docs have been removed from MSDN, but [here's one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242738.aspx).